# Is there a reasonable notion of the fixed point of a profunctor?

Tags: category-theory

Is there a reasonable notion of the fixed point of a profunctor?

I guess one would want initial/terminal algebras of a endoprofunctor?

I suppose one would impredicatively encode in Set as something like

$$ \mu H (a) = \forall X,  (\forall b, H(X(b), X(b)) \rightarrow X(a) $$

$$ \nu H (a) = \Sigma X, X(a) \times (\forall b, H(X(b), X(b)) $$

I think in a prover like Coq one would want a recursive type like

```
CoInductive nu H a :=
| nu_map: (forall b, H (nu b) (nu b)) -> nu H a -> nu H a.
Inductive mu H a :=
| mu_map: (forall b, H (mu b) (mu b)) -> mu H a -> mu H a.
```

But these all seem very strange.

You would intuit the fixed point as repeated product of profunctor compositions but this is strange.

$$ \mu H(a) = \Sigma b, H(a, b) \times \mu H(b)  $$

```
Inductive mu H a :=
| mu_map:  H (b, a) -> mu H b -> mu H a.
```

$$ \mu H(a) = H(a, a) $$

Is also really strange.

Is there a rigorous and reasonable idea for this?

I'm most interested in encodings that support dependent induction and not just recursion. So I think some things don't quite work unless you do then "from outside" so to speak.

Comment: It could be that you're looking for [coends](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end). I don't have any great insight to offer about them, but they always seemed vaguely fixpointy to me. [This book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503) is the canonical reference on the topic, and is great, though it's very much from a maths perspective rather than a programming one.

Comment: coends are akin to a trace operator; *ends* are akin to fixed points (I can expand on this). Yet, let me think about this for a while: there is a notion of "initial algebra / terminal coalgebra" for an endo-1-cell of a bicategory. I have never thought to relate it to ends, but it feels quite natural now that you point it out.

Comment: Forget about ends. I think I can reproduce at least the assumptions of Adamek existence theorem for final coalgebras (initial algebras) and Lambek lemma (the coalgebra/algebra map of an initial object is an iso). It just gets quite technical very fast, and one has to specialise that approach to the bicat of profunctors.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}$I suspect this approach turns out to be too abstract, but it's the best I can come up with.

Caveat emptor: I'll work with coalgebras, one can easily dualise to algebras (although theorems are known and easy for algebras, not for coalgebras).

Fix a 2-category $\cal K$. First, one needs the following definitions/theorems:

1. the category of coalgebras of an endo-1-cell of $\cal K$
2. Lambek lemma: if $(X,a)$ is a terminal coalgebra, then $a : X\to FX$ is an isomorphism.
3. Adamek theorem: the terminal coalgebra is obtained from the limit of the opchain
   $$ 1 \leftarrow F1 \leftarrow FF1 \leftarrow \dots$$

Now, for what concerns 1:

**Definition.** Let $F : A \to A$ be a endo-1-cell of $\cal K$. An $F$-coalgebra is a pair $(X,\alpha)$ where $X : B \to A$ and $\alpha$ is a 2-cell $X \Rightarrow FX$. A morphism of coalgebras $(X, \alpha) \to (Y, \beta)$ consists of a 2-cell $\nu : X \Rightarrow Y$ such that the square
$$\begin{CD}
X @>\nu>> Y \\ 
@V\alpha VV @VV\beta V \\ 
FX @>>F\nu> FY
\end{CD}$$ is commutative.

With this definition, one can reproduce the proof of Lambek's lemma, since it remains a tautology that every algebra map $\alpha : X \to FX$ is an algebra morphism between $(X, \alpha)$ and $(FX, F\alpha)$.

The other interesting fact is that one can -at least try to- reproduce the following theorem:
[image]

The important fact is that

1. A 0-cell $X$ of $\cal K$ "has a terminal object" if the terminal arrow $X \to 1$ has a right adjoint.
2. such right adjoint is the (absolute) right lifting of the identity of $1$ alont $X\to 1$, thus yielding a unique 2-cell $u : F{\bf 1} \Rightarrow \bf 1$ that we can use to start the opchain:

$$ {\bf 1} \overset{u}\leftarrow F{\bf 1} \overset{Fu}\leftarrow FF{\bf 1} \leftarrow FFF{\bf 1} \leftarrow\dots $$

Now, the terminal $F$-coalgebra *should be* the limit of this opchain, yielding a(n invertible) 2-cell $\sigma : T \Rightarrow FT$ by universal property.

Now: how does this story specialise to the case of ${\cal K}=$ the bicategory of profunctors?

Comment: You would think there would be a similar thing for the fixed point of a relation you could base the profunctor approach off of. But I'm not at all familiar with the area.